# Passing data to modal from button

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

I want to make a post request to my django view with query params. The query params are coming from the html template. On accept button in template, a modal opens. And there is an accept button in the modal. I want to pass the data from button to the modal and then onclick of modal button, it will make an ajax call to the view. But I am not able to pass the values from button to the modal.
Here is my code:

Button part of the template:(The values `{{ supervisor.supervisor.user.id }}` and `{{ supervisor.supervisor.user.id }}` are accessible here.)

```
{% for supervisor in proposal.supervisors %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {% if supervisor.committee_status == 0 %}
                                        <span class="badge badge-warning text-dark">Pending</span>
                                    {% elif supervisor.committee_status == 1 %}
                                        <span class="badge badge-success text-success">Accepted</span>
                                    {% elif supervisor.committee_status == 2 %}
                                        <span class="badge badge-danger text-danger">Rejected</span>
                                    {% elif supervisor.committee_status == 3 %}
                                        <a href = "{% url 'proposal_modification' proposal.proposal.id supervisor.supervisor.user.id%}">
                                        <span class="badge badge-info text-info " style="text-decoration: underline;"> Modifications</span>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#acceptModal" data-supervisor-id="{{ supervisor.supervisor.user.id }}" data-proposal-id="{{ proposal.proposal.id }}">Accept</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rejectModal" data-supervisor-id="{{ supervisor.supervisor.user.id }}" data-proposal-id="{{ proposal.proposal.id }}">Reject</button>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            
                        {% endfor %}
```

Modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="acceptModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="acceptModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="acceptModalLabel">Accept Proposal</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- Add content for the Accept modal here -->
                Are you sure you want to accept this proposal?
                This action cannot be undone!
                <p>Supervisor ID: <span id="modalSupervisorId"></span></p>
        <p>Proposal ID: <span id="modalProposalId"></span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="acceptProposal()" data-supervisor-id="{{ supervisor.supervisor.user.id }}" data-proposal-id="{{ proposal.proposal.id }}">Accept</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function acceptProposal() {
    // Get the proposal ID or other relevant data
    var supervisorId = $('#acceptModal').find('.btn-success').data('supervisor-id');

    var proposalId = $('#acceptModal').find('.btn-success').data('proposal-id');


    // Send the data to the Django view using AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/accept_proposal',  // Replace with the actual URL of your Django view
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            proposalId: proposalId
        },
        success: function (response) {
            // Handle success
            console.log('Proposal accepted:', response);
            // You may close the modal or perform other actions as needed
            $('#acceptModal').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function (error) {
            // Handle error
            console.error(error)
        }
    });
}
```

The value of `supervisorId` and `proposalID` in the js file is coming as empty string. This is because it is getting values `{{ supervisor.supervisor.user.id }}` and `{{ supervisor.supervisor.user.id }}`  from the modal and these values in modal are not present. How can I get these from button.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the values from the button to the modal and then to the JavaScript function, you need to make a few adjustments in your code.

Update the modal trigger buttons to include the data attributes:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success accept-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#acceptModal" data-supervisor-id="{{ supervisor.supervisor.user.id }}" data-proposal-id="{{ proposal.proposal.id }}">Accept</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger reject-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rejectModal" data-supervisor-id="{{ supervisor.supervisor.user.id }}" data-proposal-id="{{ proposal.proposal.id }}">Reject</button>
```

Update the modal to use `event.relatedTarget` to access the button that triggered the modal. This way, you can extract the data attributes from the triggering button:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="acceptModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="acceptModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <!-- ... other modal code ... -->
    <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Add content for the Accept modal here -->
        Are you sure you want to accept this proposal?
        This action cannot be undone!
        <p>Supervisor ID: <span id="modalSupervisorId"></span></p>
        <p>Proposal ID: <span id="modalProposalId"></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success accept-btn-modal">Accept</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Update the JavaScript to handle the `show.bs.modal` event to extract and set the data attributes when the modal is shown:

```js
$('#acceptModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
    var supervisorId = button.data('supervisor-id');
    var proposalId = button.data('proposal-id');

    // Set the data in the modal
    $('#modalSupervisorId').text(supervisorId);
    $('#modalProposalId').text(proposalId);

    // Attach the data to the Accept button in the modal
    $('.accept-btn-modal').data('supervisor-id', supervisorId);
    $('.accept-btn-modal').data('proposal-id', proposalId);
});

// Update the acceptProposal function to use the data from the modal button
function acceptProposal() {
    var supervisorId = $('.accept-btn-modal').data('supervisor-id');
    var proposalId = $('.accept-btn-modal').data('proposal-id');

    // Rest of your AJAX code...
}
```